# linq SingleorDefault

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to return a single row from the users table using domain account id as my primary and unique key

However when i use singleordefault and see its sql translation it performs entire select * from Users

my query is..

```
var user = base.SingleorDefault(t=>t.domainaccountid)
```

i want this to return just one row!

Comment: Old question, but `SingleOrDefault` has to query the entire table because it has to check that there is a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Where` along with `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var user = base.Where(t => t.domainaccountid == 123).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: SingleorDefault(pred) still does a `WHERE`, so I don't think this is directly related (although `FirstOrDefault` may be desirable for the `TOP 1` behaviour)

Answer (score 4):

What is `base` ? Is it possible that you've coerced it to `IEnumerable<T>` at some point, rather than `IQueryable<T>`? **that** would cause this. Note that database composition is only possible when using `IQueryable<T>`, so if any of your methods have returned something *other* than this, composition will end.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var user = base.SingleorDefault(t=>t.domainaccountid==123);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

SingleOrDefault looks for unique entries, it should be doing:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM TABLE
```

It does this so that if it finds 2 results it will throw an exception as it is not unique.

If you don't care about finding it as a unique object, as you have other measure in place to prevent duplicates; or just don't care you can use FirstOrDefault in the following way:

```
array.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == someOtherId);
```

This will perform the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE
```

This will get your results quicker, especially in larger tables, because it will return as soon as the first result is found.